# Calls to local host not working with ReactJS/Axios/Express

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, express, axios

I am trying to build a full stack app using ReactJS for the frontend and ExpressJS for the backend. I use Axios to make calls from my frontend to my backend. When I make those calls, I get these errors:

[image: Errors in browser console]

My express index file:

```js
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')

var app = express()

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`)
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")))
```

My get call from React frontend:

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios.get("http://localhost:5000/servers.json").then((res => {
    this.setState({ servers: res.data })
  }))
}
```

React server is running on port 3000 and Express server is running port 5000, so there shouldn't be a conflict there...

Comment: Can you show the backend routes file?

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer the public folder just holds the servers.json file. It loads when I go to http://localhost:5000/servers.json

Comment: Please update question with the errors

Comment: @Maroshii sorry, I thought I did. Just updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error **http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin** is because of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), a security feature that's restricting your react script from accessing/communicating your server since they are from ***different origins***. Please note that for documents or scripts to be considered as having the **same origin** they need to have the same ***protocol*** (e.g http / https), ***hostname*** (e.g localhost / www.my-server.com) and ***port***. In your case port the react script runs at port 3000 while the express script is running on port 5000, thus the error.

To solve this, you need to enable [CORS - Cross Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) on your server side code. First install the cors dependency using the command

> npm install cors

Then update the code in your server to look as follows:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express()

app.use(cors())

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`)
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")))
```

Hopefully this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a basic cors issue. Add [this cors middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to your express server. It's the state of the art solution to this problem.

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
var cors = require('cors')

var app = express()

app.use(cors())

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`)
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")))
```

If you are interested about cors in general, check out the [wikipedia page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing#:~:text=Cross%2DOrigin%20Resource%20Sharing%20(CORS,%2DPolicy%20(SOP)%20untersagt.).